# Name of dice-rolling board game

Tags: identify-this-game

There's a game where you roll (usually three) dice and then can combine them to claim items on the board. Play proceeds clockwise with each person using one, two, or three of their dice to claim resources, millitary power, peeks (find out what the next combat card will be) or (+2) dice modifiers from the board. The three resources are gold, wood, and stone.

In the winter of each year there's a combat phase and everyone fights the next card on the deck. There's a reward for those who win and a penalty for those who lose.

After each reward-claiming phase you can spend your resources to build structures to gain various bonuses and also victory points (which is how you win the game).

What's this game called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you're talking about Kingsburg https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/27162/kingsburg

I haven't played it but I've watched reviews and it looks similar to what you describe.

Comment: I've played the game and this totally sounds like Kingsburg.